# How can I format a DatePicker to display the date format day / month / year?

Tags: datepicker, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm using the Windows Phone 8.1 [DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker.aspx)

It's displaying the date as **month/day/year** by default and I can't see any way to change this to the 'correct' way of **day/month/year**.

This is how I declare the DatePicker

```
<DatePicker Name="datePicker" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MonthFormat="{}{month.full}"/>
```

displaying it as

[image]

I can see in the linked msdn article that I can use a [DateTimeFormatter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windows/apps/windows.globalization.datetimeformatting.datetimeformatter.aspx) in conjunction with ComboBox selectors but that's not an option for me.

Is it possible?

Comment: A downvote and no comment.... is this place turning into reddit? What's wrong with the question?

Comment: lol don't try and make sense of the downvote trolls. Just don't make eye contact and they will go away.

Comment: That being said, have you tried editing the DatePicker template?

Comment: no, how could I go about editing the template?

Comment: When in the xaml view, click on the xaml object you want to edit. Now click on the object browser (you might need to open it in view menu) right click on your object and click edit as template

Comment: That's from memory so the names might vary but that's the gist. You'll get the xaml that makes your control and you can mod it however.

Comment: @DaveDev Not sure if you really want to mess with the Culture Info settings. If you want DD/MM/YYYY, change the default language/culture away from `en-US` in the Package.appxmanifest.  Otherwise, you may want to take a look at `System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` along with the rest of the `System.Globalization`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Edit the Template

In Xaml every control has a style which you can manipulate, to change it's look and feel. Controls also inherit from one another, for example a date picker is made up of a button and a content container. And a button is made up of a border and a content container.

To Update the date pickers style.. Right click on the date picker control in visual studio from the Menu click edit template then click edit a copy. For this example you want to edit the style of the button template with in the date picker Template...

You will also need to create a Converter class to used in the template

This answer worked for me
Page with date picker...

```
<Page
x:Class="DatePikerAnswer.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:DatePikerAnswer"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- Format Converter -->
    <local:DateConverter x:Key="FormatConverter"/>

    <!-- My Button Style-->
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneBorderThickness">2.5</Thickness>
    <FontWeight x:Key="PhoneButtonFontWeight">Semibold</FontWeight>
    <x:Double x:Key="TextStyleLargeFontSize">18.14</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinHeight">57.5</x:Double>
    <x:Double x:Key="PhoneButtonMinWidth">109</x:Double>
    <Thickness x:Key="PhoneTouchTargetOverhang">0,9.5</Thickness>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent"/>
    <Style x:Key="MyButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneBorderThickness}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonFontWeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="9.5,0"/>
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinHeight}"/>
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneButtonMinWidth}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="PointerOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="PointerOver" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Pressed" To="Normal">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualTransition>
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <PointerDownThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Grid"/>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBorderThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="Border">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource ButtonDisabledBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="{ThemeResource PhoneTouchTargetOverhang}">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" 
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                              Content="{Binding Content,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Converter={StaticResource FormatConverter},ConverterParameter=\{0:dd/MM/yyyy\}}" 
                                              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <!--DatePicker Style-->
    <FontFamily x:Key="PhoneFontFamilyNormal">Segoe WP</FontFamily>
    <x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">20.26</x:Double>
    <Style x:Key="MyDatePickerStyle1" TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0,0,0,-3" 
                                          Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" 
                                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                BorderThickness="2.5" 
                                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                                Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                                IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}"
                                Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}"
                                Padding="6.5,0,0,3"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>

 <Grid>
```

```
  </Grid>
</Page>
```

Converter Class ...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace DatePikerAnswer
{
  class DateConverter : IValueConverter
  {
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
       if (value != null)
        {
            ///Convert Class throws exception so can not convert to date time
            string TheCurrentDate = value.ToString();

            string[] Values = TheCurrentDate.Split('/');
            string Day, Month, Year;

            Day = Values[1];
            Month = Values[0];
            Year = Values[2];

            string retvalue = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", Day, Month, Year);
            return retvalue;
       }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
  }
}
```

The End Result is ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer! I'll give it a try Monday morning and let you know how I got on with it.

Comment: I gave this a try - it looks good but when you tap the date it throws an `ArgumentException` with the message "The parameter is incorrect. Placement target needs to be in the visual tree." I can't figure out how to fix it!

Comment: after further investigation it seems this error is not the fault of your code - it's a bug in my app! feck...

Comment: @StuartSmith It will not work for German localization and probably some other regions due to different data format. btw: any idea why "value" in converter is not possible to convert into DateTime?

Comment: kubakist, you are correct... The code may not work for many Cultures. I did this for US Cultures, I did not change this for German and try it out. Since the convert kept giving me exceptions, I used parsing the string,  One would have to parse the date time string returned for a given culture to get the correct results.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to show Date as 'Month Year', I tried some solutions I thought about but they didn't work , searched a little and finally found this question and the answer by StuartSmith.
Based on his answer I came up with similar solution that works around localization issue mentioned in comment by Kubaskista

> @StuartSmith It will not work for German localization and probably some other regions due to different data format. btw: any idea why "value" in converter is not possible to convert into DateTime?

1-  Define Date Picker in xaml, give it name "FirstDatePicker" and then from Designer edit template then choose edit a copy.

[image: Date Picker Style]

```
<DatePicker x:Name="FirstDatePicker" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,12,0,0"    CalendarIdentifier="GregorianCalendar" DayVisible="False" Padding="0" Style="{StaticResource DatePickerStyle}" RequestedTheme="Light"/>
```

2- Right Click on FlyoutButton -> Additional Templates -> Edit Generated Content -> Edit a copy.

[image]

3- Inside content template, We will bind directly to Date property of FirstDatePicker and by using of StringFormatConverter you can format the date as you wish and override culture also.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="DateFormatTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date, ConverterParameter=MMMM yyyy, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}, ElementName=FirstDatePicker, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

4- Add StringFormatConverter to solution, Don't forget to add it to resources section of page.

```
  public class DateFormatConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert ( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
    {
        if(!(value is DateTime || value is DateTimeOffset) || parameter == null) return value;
        if(value is DateTime)
        {
            var date = (DateTime)value;
            return date.ToString(parameter.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
        else
        {
            var date = (DateTimeOffset)value;
            return date.ToString(parameter.ToString(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack ( object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Note:You can change 'CultureInfo.CurrentCulture' to new Culture("ar-EG") as example or use language passed in converter.

Finally, Here is what i have in resources section of page

```
 <converters:DateFormatConverter x:Key="DateFormatConverter"/>
 <x:Double x:Key="ContentControlFontSize">20.26</x:Double>
    <FontWeight x:Key="PhoneButtonFontWeight2">Semibold</FontWeight>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DateFormatTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Date, ConverterParameter=MMMM yyyy, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}, ElementName=FirstDatePicker, Mode=OneWay}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="DatePickerStyle" TargetType="DatePicker">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlFontSize}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource DatePickerForegroundThemeBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DatePicker">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Margin="0,0,0,-3" Style="{StaticResource HeaderContentPresenterStyle}"/>
                        <Button x:Name="FlyoutButton" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="2.5" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}" Padding="12,10" Margin="0"   ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DateFormatTemplate}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```