# How can Xamarin DatePicker show day of week?

Tags: xamarin.forms, datepicker

I tried Xamarin Forms DatePicker in iOS and UWP with Format = "D".
In iOS, the day of week shows up in the DatePicker, looking like

> Sunday, April 24, 2016

But in UWP, DatePicker doesn't show the day of week, it shows:

> April 24 2016

So, my question is:

How can I display the day of week in DatePicker of UWP?

Here is my code in xaml:

```xml
<DatePicker WidthRequest="350" HeightRequest="30" Margin="20,0,0,200" x:Name="DtPicker" Format="D" />
```

Comment: If you do the formatting yourself, does it still not show the day of the week? Something like Format="dddd, MMMM d, yyyy".

Comment: No, nothing changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I want to talk about `Format = "D"`. From document [The Long Date ("D") Format Specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-long-date-d-format-specifier), this is a string value .However can not be shown in DatePicker.

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("D", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
// Displays Thursday, April 10, 2008                        
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("D", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")));
// Displays quinta-feira, 10 de abril de 2008                        
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("D", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX")));
// Displays jueves, 10 de abril de 2008
```

Now you can have a look at **[DatePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/date-picker)** designed in UWP, it can not show day of week .

[image]

**So the only way that is to custom DatePicker.**

In Xamarin Forms , using **[Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/renderers#views)** can custom `DatePciker` in UWP .

Create a **custom DatePicker** in Forms :

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
}
```

Using it in **Xaml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App8"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App8.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Padding="100">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" 
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        <local:CustomDatePicker />
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Then in UWP , create the **custom renderer class** :

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomDatePicker), typeof(CustomDatePickerRenderer))]
namespace App8.UWP
{
    public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
                var formatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("dayofweek");
                DateTime dateToFormat = DateTime.Now;
                var mydate = formatter.Format(dateToFormat);
                Control.Header = mydate;
                Control.DateChanged += Control_DateChanged;
            }
        }

        private void Control_DateChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.DatePickerValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            var formatter = new Windows.Globalization.DateTimeFormatting.DateTimeFormatter("month day dayofweek year");
            DateTime dateToFormat = e.NewDate.DateTime;
            var mydate = formatter.Format(dateToFormat);
            Control.Header = mydate;
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: Here I just set the day of week in `Header` of `DatePicker`, because not founding the way to modify the UI of Picker alredy. I think there will need more time to find the best solution if keep researching [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.datepicker) .

The current display effect is **as follows**:

[image]

Comment: You are right, now I do see the dayOfWeek, thanks! I thought this is an issue of datePicker when running under UWP because dayOfWeek shows in iOS. Do you think it is possible to switch month and day in the datePicker, like "29 | August | 2019"?

Comment: @renintx It is possible. Here is a reference discussion , you can have a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26422526/how-can-i-format-a-datepicker-to-display-the-date-format-day-month-year